# How to get variable from django url

Tags: django, url

I'm new to Django and would like to know how to get a variable from a url.  I have tried this:

```
url(r'^(?P<name>)/$', employeedetail, name='employeedetail'),
```

which goes to this view

```
def employeedetail(request, name):
    return render(request, 'employee/detail.html')
```

but I get an error: employeedetail() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'

Is the code wrong or do I need to type in the url in a particular way?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stack Overflow. The best place to find that would be in the django docs. Have you worked through the tutorial yet?

Comment: I have but I can't find the problem. @The_Cthulhu_Kid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex is wrong; you haven't provided any characters to match. It should be something like:

```
 r'^(?P<name>\w+)/$
```

which matches all alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following solution

in your urls.py

For a string parameter in url use following syntax

```
url(r'^(?P<name>[\w\-]+)/$',employeedetail, name='employeedetail')
```

This will even allow the strings to pass in your url.

And access name parameter in your view

```
def employeedetail(request, name):
    print name
    return render(request, 'employee/detail.html')
```

Hope this will help you